# Find nearest accessible number in 2d array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a 2d array containing numbers. It could like this:

```
11211
1  31
1 111
1  11
13111
```

The numbers 1 are "walls", 2 is the entrance and 3 are the points we want to reach. As you can see we have two occurences of 3, and they are not equally close. I need to find the closest one. Remember the input array is random and does not have to look like this.

I was thinking something along these lines of how to solve it:
Find the entrance first. This can only be done in O(n^2) (worst case) time, since the entrance may be anywhere in the array, and doesn't have to be along the edge. I can implement this without any issues.

Then I would need to search from the entrance point out in the array. Whenever I find a number 3 I would need to remember that I visited it, and the distance between the points (2 and 3 from the example). Lets say I find the number 3 furthest away from the entrance. This is obviously not the closest point(If we look at the example). I would need to jump back to the entrance and search again. I thought about having a sort of real time counter, counting the steps, so that if I ever do more steps than the treasure I just found, i would just stop and say that the before found treasure was the closest.

I think there is a much better way of implementing it efficiently, but I really can't think of how to do it. I tried searching for Dijkstra's algorithm, but it seems that it finds the shortest path from the entrance to all numbers in the array(the numbers being the targeted number 3). I guess you could just filter out the shortest of them, but how exactly would you implement this in Java?

I'm not looking for complete code, but only something to guide me, so that I can understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming "distance" you mean walking in empty spaces.

1. Start from entrance, get the element left, up, down and right to it, while do not go into it if that was already marked visited. If you see a wall or hit the edge, mark it visited and ignore that. If you see an empty space, put the element in a queue.
2. Mark the entrance visited.
3. Dequeue an element from the queue in (1)
4. Using the dequeued element as new "entrance", repeat (1)-(3) until you hit a `3`, and in this case, stop. That `3` is the closest to entrance
5. In case you don't meet any `3` and you get everything visited already in (1), it means there is no `3` reachable from the entrance.

This is an instance of [Breadth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), and using technique similar to [Flood fill.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floodfill)

In addition, which direction you visit in (1) could affect the final result if and only if there are multiple `3` having same, and shortest, distance.

Comment: I know there can be two elements that have equal distance, from the entrance. If that is the case, i just need to pick either one. But thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2):

I love bellman ford for problems like this. Certainly its N^3 (In this case), but its so simple to implement.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm

In your case :

**Setup** 
   Create a 2D array ShortestDistance and fill it with infinity.
   Go over the array and set ShortestDistance as 0 where there is a door. These are grid points where we can reach in 0 distance.

**Algorithm**

```
   For itr in 0 to N // (Max Distance between any door and 
      For i in 0 to N // row index
         For j in 0 to N //column number
           If Grid[i][j] == 1
              Continue; //its a wall and it can't propagate shortest distance
           else 
               ShortestDistance[i][j] = min(
                                           ShortestDistance[i][j],  //current value
                                           1 + (ShortestDistance among all neighbours*) //reduced shortest path.
```

*In each step we are updating the shortest distance of reaching a place by shortest distance of reaching one of its neighbors + 1, or the current value itself.

**Post Processing**
Go through over the ShortestDistance 2D array and print the minimum value corresponding to a '3' type point.